# Calculate the order of $A(F_p)$

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, group-theory

I am asked to calculate the cardinality of the set $A(F_p)$, which includes the matrices of the form $$\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$ in $GL_2(F_p)$ (p is a prime number).

My approach is to count by columns, so for the first column, I have $p-1$ choices ($p$ choices for $a$, minus the zero vector). And for the second column, I have to minus the number of vectors included in the span of the first column, which I don't know what that is (I still have $p$ choices for $b$), then finally multiply them together. I'm not sure if this is the way to count.

I would appreciate any help to find the number of vectors in the span of $\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: The span of $\begin{pmatrix}a\\0\end{pmatrix}$ consists of the multiples of this vector. Does any of these multiples have the form $\begin{pmatrix}b\\1\end{pmatrix}$? (look at the second entry)

Comment: It doesn't seem like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the affine group $\operatorname{Aff}(\Bbb F_p)$ of order $p(p-1)$, see
[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group). So the cardinality is $p(p-1)$, since $a\in \Bbb F_p^{\times}$ and $b\in \Bbb F_p$.