# show that $AGL(1, \mathbb F_p) \simeq \mathbb F_p \rtimes \mathbb F^{\times}_p$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, galois-theory

$AGL(1, \mathbb F_p)$ is the group formed by transformations from $\gamma_{A,b}: \mathbb{F_p}$ to $\mathbb F_p$ with $\gamma_{a,b}(u) = au+b$.

I know that the following group is a subgroup
$$ T = \{ \gamma_{1,b} | b \in \mathbb{F_p} \} $$
and that
$$ AGL(1, \mathbb{F_p}) / T \simeq \mathbb{F^{\times}_p}$$
although I don't really see why this last isomorphism holds, and how to conclude the following.
$$AGL(1, \mathbb F_p) \simeq \mathbb F_p \rtimes \mathbb F^{\times}_p$$

Can somehone help me to prove this?

Comment: This is the affine group of $\Bbb F_p$ of order $p(p-1)$. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group) for details. It is clear that it is a semidirect product. Indeed, write it as matrices like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3837782/calculate-the-order-of-af-p?rq=1). The semidirect product is given by the natural action of $\Bbb F_p^{\times}$ on $\Bbb F_p$ by multiplication.

Comment: The intuition for why it's true is that every affine transformation can be decomposed into a linear transformation and a translation. Using that intuition, which element of the affine general linear group do you think pairs with e.g. $(4,7)$?